# Swift - saving a file to icloud drive

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, icloud

I am trying to save a file to iCloud with the following code in my iOS app:

```
        if let containerUrl = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents") {
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: containerUrl.path, isDirectory: nil) {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: containerUrl, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        
        let fileUrl = containerUrl.appendingPathComponent("test.txt")
        do {
            let accData = String(data: NSData.init(contentsOf: file.fileURL)! as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
            print(accData)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                try? accData.data(using: .utf8)?.write(to: fileUrl)

            }
            
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

fileUrl looks as follows `"file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~project~iCloud/Documents/"`. On the Phone under Settings -> iCloud -> Manage Data there is a new dir caled iCloud (see screenshot):

[image]

and when going into the dir i can see my saved file:
[image]

How can I save it into "iCloud Drive" instead so it is also visible from other locations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving a file to icloud drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65173861/saving-a-file-to-icloud-drive)

Comment: No. I have used the code from this answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the issue by naming the icloud bucket with the same name as bundle id of the app -> then upgrading the version number of the app

Comment: I've done your exact steps and incremented the version number to 1.0.1 but still doesnt show in File app any ideas? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76131000/cannot-save-files-to-icloud-drive-and-have-it-appear-in-file-app

Comment: I'm unsure why this worked but this apparently was the answer. Here's what I did. I made a new iCloud Container with the same name as my bundle id. Before I was using iCloud.AppName. now iCloud.(bundleidentifier) example iCloud.com.website.MyApp 

My info plist was the same from this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForDocumentsIniCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH2-SW20)  

The folder showed up in iCloud Drive as I wanted it to. I did upgrade the version number and build number.

Answer (score -1):

`Documents` is the directory of the documents visible to the user. Save the document to the `Library` instead:

```
if let containerUrl = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Library") {
```

Comment: hmm where exactly would the file then go? when I do it I can not find it anywhere? I need it in the "iCloud Drive/Documents"

Comment: All iCloud Drive documents are visible to the user. When it is saved in the library directory, the user cannot see it.